# How can I place divs absolutely in a 3x3 grid with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sliding-tile-puzzle

I'm trying to create a 3x3 puzzle, grid of blocks of divs and each time the page refreshes, js creates and array of random order of numbers from 1-9 and uses them to create the 'blocks', gives them the corresponding id's and appends them to the container
But i'm having issues, as not all the blocks are displayed. Some blocks  (precisely 2 blocks) are still in the default 'absolute' position (0, 0) while the rest are okay.

Please can anyone help find out what's wrong ?

> #randomOrder is and an array of 1-9 randomly ordered

#### # CSS Snippet :

```css
.container{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: flex;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #000;
}

.block{
    width: 31%;
    height: 31%;
    margin: 1.5px;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    background: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 2px solid #000;    
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #555 inset;
}
```

#### # JS Snippet:

```js
let r = 1, c = 1
let x = 4, y = 4
randomOrder.forEach(el => {
    block = document.createElement('div')
    block.classList.add('block')
    block.id = "b" + el
    if(r <= 3){
        if(c <= 3){
            block.style.left = x + 'px'
            block.style.top = y + 'px'
            c++
            x += 98
        }
        else{
            c = 1
            x = 4
            y += 98
            r++
        }
    }

    if (el == 9) {
        block.innerText = ""
    }
    else {
        block.innerText = el
    }
    container.appendChild(block)
})
```

**This is what I'm getting below :**

[image]

**But This Is What I'm Expecting : (But in any random order)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these issues in your logic:

1. The inner `if` condition should be `if (c < 3)` instead of `if (c <= 3)`, since `c` still gets incremented in that `if` block
2. The assignment to `style.left` and `style.top` should also happen when execution gets into the `else` block, so those two assignments should be made *before* the `if`
3. `block` should be declared with a `var` or `let` or `const` keyword. Now it is implicitly defined as a global variable which is not good practice, and not allowed when running in strict mode.

Not an issue, but the `if (r <= 3)` really is not necessary -- this will always be the case.

With those remarks taken into account, the relevant code becomes:

```
    const block = document.createElement('div')
    block.classList.add('block')
    block.id = "b" + el
    block.style.left = x + 'px'
    block.style.top = y + 'px'
    if(c < 3){
        c++
        x += 98
    }
    else{
        c = 1
        x = 4
        y += 98
        r++
    }
```

There is however an easier way to determine `x` and `y`, using the remainder operator (`%`) and the index you can get as argument in the `forEach` callback.

Unrelated, but the final `if..else` can be shortened with the conditional operator (`? :`):

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const randomOrder = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

randomOrder.forEach((el, i) => {
    const block = document.createElement('div');
    block.classList.add('block');
    block.id = "b" + el;
    block.style.left = (4 + 98*(i % 3)) + 'px'
    block.style.top = (4 + 98*Math.floor(i / 3)) + 'px'
    block.innerText = el == 9 ? "" : el;
    container.appendChild(block);
});
```

```css
.container{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: flex;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #000;
}

.block{
    width: 31%;
    height: 31%;
    margin: 1.5px;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    background: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 2px solid #000;    
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #555 inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Here is what the `%` and `Math.floor` expressions evaluate to for all the possible values of the index `i`:

| index `i` | `i % 3` | `Math.floor(i / 3)` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 |

So you can see that `i % 3` represents a column index and `Math.floor(i / 3)` a row index.

Comment: It works, thanks! But i don't really understand what happens when calculating the top and left of the blocks. Can you please explain the logic so i cant fully understand my code ?

Comment: Which code are you asking about?

Comment: block.style.left = (4 + 98*(i % 3)) + 'px'
block.style.top = (4 + 98*Math.floor(i / 3)) + 'px'

Comment: Maybe read about the `%` operator and `Math.floor`... I added a table with the values that these expression produce, although it is easy to find that out yourself.

Comment: Oh nice I understand faster now. The logic is very useful, then using the if statements and stuff. Thanks alot! I'll be posting a new problem in a bit XD